# Export html table without the 1st column to excel

Tags: html, excel

Greeting, i need to export a html table without the 1st column to excel.
My code does the exporting, but i want to remove that 1st column.

I found a way to remove the 1st column, like so :

```
$("#dt_myTable th:first-child, #dt_myTable td:first-child").remove();
```

However it requires table's id, and i only have my tab object which i got with

```
tab = document.getElementById('dt_myTable');
```

Here is my function :

```
function exportToExcel()
{
    var tab_text="<table border='1px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
    var timeDate = getCurrentTimeDate();
    var fileName = "registers"+timeDate+".xls";

    tab = document.getElementById('dt_myTable');


    for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {   
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,"");
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); 


    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))    
    {
        txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
        txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
        txtArea1.document.close();
        txtArea1.focus(); 

        sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true, fileName);

    }  
    else 
        sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text)); 

    return (sa);
}
```

Comment: "It requires the table's id" - you *have* the table's id.  What's the problem exactly ?

Comment: I have id of my table, yes, but what i want to do is : create another table which is equal to mine, remove this table's 1st column and send it to excel.
Even if i give this new table an id, i think i can't access it via $('#table_id') since it is not anywhere in my html document, or can i?

It's just i tried it but the function did noting at all.